# Magento x 2.4 get.php error

Tags: php, error, log, pub

In var/log both in exception.log and in system.log I have this type of error that I don't know what is due and I have no idea how to debug it, can someone give me clarification on what is due and possibly how to fix it.

```
main.ERROR: Warning: stripos(): needle is not a string or an integer in [root_path]/pub/get.php on line 22.

$isAllowed = function ($resource, array $allowedResources) {
    foreach ($allowedResources as $allowedResource) {
        if (0 === stripos($resource, $allowedResource)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```